# ld returned 1 exit status - c file structure

Tags: c, cygwin, ld

I am editing an open source C project to customize it for my usage. Basically it has the following file structure:

```
                  |--- /include ----- loremipsum.h
                  |
/loremipsum ----- |--- /ex      ----- loremipsum.c and more
                  |
                  |--- /src     ----- other helpful functions
```

In loremipsum.h one can find a list of functions that are defined in /src, via

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

but this has not been edited by me, so i suppose it should work.

In loremipsum.c there are:

- #include "loremipsum.h"
- plenty of `extern void function_defined_in_ex()`(*1*)
- some more definitions.
- main

After editing the c-files and trying to recreate a new exefile via

```
$ gcc  loremipsum.c -o customloremipsum.exe
```

first I got an error, that loremipsum.h was not found, so I changed the include to "path/to/include/loremipsum.h", I did that in all .c files with that include.

Then, all of the (*1*) had an error, namely
"/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBt2CkE.o:loremipsum.c:(.text+0x3745): undefined reference to function_defined_in_ex'
ld returned 1 exit status".
I really can't figure out, why.

I think the first include error is already strange, in my understanding, there should be no problem to find the .h file. Also, I can't figure out, how to make clear where to find the functions in (*1*).

I'm very sorry for that long post, I'm just afraid, I'm forgetting something fundamental.

I am working on Windows 10 and compiling in a Cygwin shell.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess the project would have had some build instructions. It might be worth reading them? Most likely, it will be expected to be built using `make` or something similar.

Comment: Works aswell, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler where to look for include files using the `-I` parameter, for example:

```
gcc -I../include loremipsum.c -o customloremipsum.exe
```

Don't specify the full path in the `#include` lines.

Any undefined references you get are cause by the linker because the `.c` files or objects or libraries defining the symbols are not compiled in yet.

Also, it's better to split compilation and linking steps to help you where things go wring. Like this:

```
gcc -c -I../include loremipsum.c -o customloremipsum.o
gcc customloremipsum.o -o customloremipsum.exe
```

Comment: am I supposed to add/remove something between -I and /include? I tried: "-I /include", "-I/include", "-I../include". my working directory is /path/to/loremipsum and i called the c-files by /ex/loremipsum.c. I get the error "loremipsum.h" no such file or directory, referring to the first include line in my .c files

Comment: I fixed it, it was supposed to be ```-Iinclude/``` - thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I was overly exited, it worked for the error that complained about #include loremipsum.h, but i still receive the list of voids, as above

Comment: If you get undefined references you need to also compile the sources that define those functions and add their compiled `.o` files to the link step.